# cating a binary in a tmux pane crashes the whole window

Tags: tmux

I have the same issue of the following question:
[tmux status-bar corrupted after catting a binary file, how to reset?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/tmux-status-bar-corrupted-after-catting-a-binary-file-how-to-reset)

and the bug that is mentioned in it does not exist any more.
So my question here is that why it is window 4 needs to be renamed?

I am using tmux 1.9a.

I did a test in my tmux with 5 windows.
after cating a binary, the encoding becomes incorrect,

[image]
Is it a known issue? is there a bug item to track it ?

Comment: Did 'reset' not work?

Comment: @DarkHeart, I don't know how to do the 'reset'.

Comment: @Alex Type `reset` and then press Enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use the command 'reset'.

ie

```
$ reset
```

or in your case :)

```
$ ⎼e⎽e├
```

The man page explain this in more detail

Answer (score 1):

run the command (in the tmux status bar) using tmux's command-mode (`C-b :` by default):

```
    # try (RESET, INT, XON, RETURN, `reset`, RETURN):
    send-keys -R C-c C-q C-m " reset" C-m ; refresh-client

    # if that doesn't work (destroy the pane):
    kill-pane ; send-keys -R ; refresh-client
```

The original answer is infeasible:  it assumes you can somehow run `reset` when the window is completely locked up.

Answer (score 0):

The corruption could be due to terminal / tmux control codes being inadvertently present in the binary data, causing the font to change, or even closing the tmux session down. In this case it's not a bug, but expected behaviour. If you want to view the contents of a binary file, then I would suggest using the `xxd` tool to prevent the 'random' string of bytes in the binary affecting tmux and the terminal.