# Sometimes my zsh messes the end of lines

Tags: command-line, zsh, command, newlines

I have this strange issue, that I cannot find the source of, nor a solution to solve.

"Sometimes" my zsh gets messed up and start display end of lines in a funny way:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the newlines are ignored and I get a funny `%` at the end of the line.

Do you know what may cause this and how to solve it?

Note: I'm running OS X, a zsh inside Iterm2 and Tmux.

Comment: Does `reset` help?

Comment: Yes, it seems to restart the session. Is it the case, or is only the display refreshed? (nice to see you here btw)

Comment: It doesn't restart the session; it just resets the terminal settings. Probably related to http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49886/70524 (you too!)

Answer (score 9):

The screenshot shows what is called "staircasing", where the newline sent from the computer to the terminal is not automatically translated to a carriage-return / line-feed by the terminal driver.

You would see this after running a program that modifies the terminal modes temporarily, but does not succeed in restoring the original modes.  You would ***never*** see this as a result of cat'ing a binary file to the screen.

You can produce this behavior on some shells (others such as `tcsh` reset the terminal modes after each command).  Here is an example using `dash`:

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
$ stty -onlcr
$ stty -a
         speed 38400 baud; rows 40; columns 80; line = 0;
                                                         intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^H; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
                                              eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
                                            werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
                   -parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
                                                                            -ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
                                                                          -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
                       opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
                       isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
                  echoctl echoke
                                $
```

The `reset` command, as suggested, will reset the terminal modes, but also resets features on the terminal itself.  You could also use

```
stty sane
```

or more specifically

```
stty onlcr
```

but `reset` involves the least typing.

Further reading:

- [**`stty`** — change and print terminal line settings](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)
- [**`tset`**, **`reset`** — terminal initialization](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tset.1.html)

Comment: `stty sane` worked for me, but `stty onlcr` did not (macOS Big Sur 11.6.5). Ran a Django migration that failed in a Docker container.